# Adding new item to ArrayList with new panel - swing Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i would like to know, how can i add a new item by new panel in Java GUI.

I have class `Program`

```
public class Program extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 public ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 public int pos;


public Program() {
    contacts.add(new Contact("John Tavares", "736426436", "Prague"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("John Doe", "725847896", "NY"));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Damien Smith", "725589963", "London"));
    pos = 0;
    initComponents();
}
```

and then some labels which show content of ArrayList, it works fine. In class `Contact` have name, tel and city.

And i have JButton New Contact which opened new Panel NewContact with text fields for name, tel and city and of course OK JButton. This works fine, too.

Can anybody help me, please, how can i get texts from text fields in NewContact and add them to ArrayList?

Thanks for any advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, u waant to add contacts with a button.
At first you have to make a new button:

```
private JButton mybutton = new JButton("Add");
```

Then you have to override the actionListener

```
private void addActionListener() {
    mybutton.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Then you have to sreach what kind of button you pressed:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
Object source = e.getSource();
if(source == mybutton)
    contacts.add(something);
}
```

Comment: oh, sorry... i mean i have JButton which opened new JPanel, ive written it wrong. It works fine all. In new JPanel i have text fields for typing new name, tel and city and when pressed "Add" button i want to add this data to ArrayList contacts

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a JTable should be used to display your data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

In you new contact form you would then add the data to the TableModel directly. The DefaultTableModel supports an addRow(...) method.

For a more complex solution that lets you add a Contact to the TableModel you will need to create a custom model. You could use a [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/).

> how can i get texts from text fields

You use the getText() method. Read the Swing tutorial. Maybe start with the section on `How to Write an Action Listener`. An ActionListener gets invoked when you click on a button.

Comment: thanks :) but id like to know how can i add new contact in new JPanel, displays my data is second thing.

Comment: You don't add a Contant to a JPanel. A Contact isn't a Swing component. You need to add the Contact information to a Swing component and then add the component to a panel.